# Dealing with date in different language using datapicker and moments

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, momentjs

I have a web site which, depending on the location, allows to set the date in different language:

Example:

```
Mercredi, Juin 06, 2012 // french
Wednesday, Jun 06, 2012 // english
```

Then these dates needs to be saved on the server using momentjs

```
moment('Tuesday, Jun 05, 2012').format(); // 2012-06-05T00:00:00+02:00
moment('Mercredi, Juin 06, 2012').format(); // NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaN+00:00
```

How can I fix this issue when the user is using a different language from the english?

P.S.:
Not sure if it can helps...
with momentsjs is possible to set the lang in this way, but the problem persists:

```
moment.lang('fr');
moment('Mercredi, Juin 06, 2012').format(); // NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaN+00:00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things missing:

1. load the appropriate [language file](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/tree/master/lang).
2. To quote from the docu: "You can create a moment from a string that can be parsed by Date.parse" [moment(String)] or "If you know the format of an input string, you can use that to parse a moment" [moment(String, String)]. So, if it isn't understood by Date.parse you need to give the date format as a second argument.

This should work then:

```
moment.lang("fr");
moment('Mercredi, Juin 06, 2012', "dddd, MMMM DD, YYYY").format();
```

also see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNwfW/2/)